# iPhone-like (slot machine) 'picker' select box for the web?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, picker

I'm looking for a iPhone-like "picker" control that I'm able to use on the web.

Accessibility is not a concern. JavaScript will be available on all clients and the web app will be run on an environment provided to the user. If the solution could gracefully degrade to a select box though, that would be great.  Flash & Silverlight are not ideal (for reasons I don't care to jump into) but similar solutions in Flash & Silverlight may  be appreciated by others.

Here's an example of the control on an iPhone:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you describe how this differs from a select box? How do you scroll it? Does it need to be smooth scrolling, etc?

Comment: Accessibility may not be a concern, but is usability? I can't imagine using something like that with a mouse. Swiping with a finger is what makes that a good interface for the iPhone. I predict difficulty for mouse and keyboard users.

Comment: @nickf Scrolling will be done via clicking (and holding) the control and dragging the mouse vertically. I was able to find a piece of code, but it only works with Mobile Safari. http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch/11

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, Usability is not a concern in this case, either. This application will be used in a touchscreen environment, but not the iPhone. The solution should be treated like a mouse is being used because the touch screen driver acts as a mouse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this question is somewhat old, but since I have an answer I could just as well give it. Other people can still be looking for it (just like I did). I created this control to use it as a plugin with jQuery. See my blog:

http://marinovdh.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/use-the-iphone-uipickerview-control-as-a-selectbox-on-your-website-with-jquery/

Comment: The blog post still exists, but when I try to download it, the link doesn't work

Comment: Please see GitHub for the latest version: https://github.com/r3wt/iPhonePicker

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something already built, which I haven't seen, but it looks like you could build one by using [YUI's](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) Carousel Control plus Animations, [as this section on the carousel control page explains](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/carousel/#animation).

Good luck!!

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion.  How would one apply that style to a select box though?  I think the better route to go is to re-style a vertical slider like is often found in jQuery.  I haven't delved into a solution met, but I'll post an update here if I ever complete one.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentOne may have what you're looking for. Check out the C1 Studio for iPhone at http://www.componentone.com. It's a suite of ASP.NET controls which mimic the Native look and feel of iPhone UI elements.

Comment: Yes, Studio for iPhone has exactly what you need. Check out PickerView, which is included in the studio.

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PickerViewiPhone/